# Returning Multiple Argument Values in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm currently building a sheet which institutes a modal/sidebar. My issue is that I really need multiple values passed from a function in my *.gs file.

Currently I know I can implement this:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myFunction).gasFunction('argument value');
```

### Index.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
    var hello = 'Not Working';
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(indexLog).logMe('hello');
    function indexLog(hello) {
        console.log(hello);
    }
</body>
</html>
```

### GAS SCRIPT

```
function logMe(hello) {
    return  hello;
}
```

So I'm in a position where I'm running a continuous method multiple times in order to return all arguments needed, ie.

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(indexLog).logMe('value 1');
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(indexLog).logMe('value 2');
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(indexLog).logMe('value 2');
```

**My values would be cell references, but I need a range not a single cell value**

I'm then taking those values and would like to build an array from those to iterate the values across my for loop function correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It was in the minute details of the methods.

**SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).getValue();**

```
function returnCellValue(cell) {
    return (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).getValue());
}
```

This will only return 1 value even if a range is inputted. **getValue()** only returns 1 value regardless of the range.

**SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).getValues();**

```
function returnCellValue(cell) {
    return (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).getValues());
}
```

Using **getValues()** passed the range as an array that I could then iterate over. Currently Google App Scripts and Sheets only support ranges for touching cells so you cannot use a comma separator to define all ranges needed if they are not neighbors of the referenced cell.